# Trying to generate tabs and their views dynamically

Tags: android, dynamic, tabs

Update:

The compile error is resolved and I found some things I didn't do right orgianlly based off the example I was following and corrected them. However when I try to run the code I get the following error. When I line by through the code I have noticed that the createTabContent inside the NewTab.setContent doesn't execute because my breakpoint in there is never tripped.

```
01-12 10:11:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(14528): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-12 10:11:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(14528): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jackman.universalav/com.jackman.universalav.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
01-12 10:11:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(14528): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
01-12 10:11:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(14528): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
01-12 10:11:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(14528): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
01-12 10:11:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(14528): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
01-12 10:11:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(14528): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-12 10:11:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(14528): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-12 10:11:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(14528): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
01-12 10:11:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(14528): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-12 10:11:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(14528): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-12 10:11:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(14528): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
01-12 10:11:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(14528): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
01-12 10:11:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(14528): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-12 10:11:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(14528): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
01-12 10:11:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(14528): at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1026)
01-12 10:11:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(14528): at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2131)
01-12 10:11:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(14528): at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:865)
01-12 10:11:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(14528): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
01-12 10:11:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(14528): at android.widget.TabHost$LabelIndicatorStrategy.createIndicatorView(TabHost.java:554)
01-12 10:11:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(14528): at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:234)
01-12 10:11:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(14528): at com.jackman.universalav.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:71)
01-12 10:11:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(14528): at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5191)
01-12 10:11:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(14528): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
01-12 10:11:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(14528): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
01-12 10:11:21.285: E/AndroidRuntime(14528): ... 11 more
```

The updated code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Create the tab host that contains the tab widget that contains the tabs
        TabHost Tabs = new TabHost(this);
        Tabs.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        //Create the tab widget  container
        TabWidget TabWidget = new TabWidget(this);
        TabWidget.setId(android.R.id.tabs);
        Tabs.addView(TabWidget, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        //the tab host needs a frame layout for the views associated with each visible tab
        FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
        frameLayout.setId(android.R.id.tabcontent);
        frameLayout.setPadding(0, 65, 0, 0);
        Tabs.addView(frameLayout, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        Tabs.setup();
        //Create the tabs
        DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        String dbQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + dbHelper.System_Table + " AS s JOIN " + dbHelper.Devices_Table + " AS d ON s." + dbHelper.Attribute_Device_ID +
            " = d." + dbHelper.Attribute_Device_ID + ";";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(dbQuery, null);
        if (c.getCount() > 0)
        {
            while (c.moveToNext())
            {
                  int iColumnDeviceType = c.getColumnIndex(dbHelper.Attribute_Device_Type);
                  int iColumnDeviceName = c.getColumnIndex(dbHelper.Attribute_Device_Name);
                  final String DeviceType = c.getString(iColumnDeviceType);
                  String DeviceName = c.getString(iColumnDeviceName);
                  String DeviceNameLabel = DeviceName.replaceAll(" ", "");
                  TabSpec NewTab = Tabs.newTabSpec("tab" + DeviceNameLabel);
                  NewTab.setIndicator(DeviceNameLabel);
                  NewTab.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory()
                  {
                    public View createTabContent(String tag)
                    {
                        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
                        LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        ll.setLayoutParams(params);
                        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                        if (DeviceType == "Receiver")
                        {

                        }
                        else if (DeviceType == "Video Player")
                        {

                        }
                        return ll;
                     }
                   });
                   Tabs.addTab(NewTab);
             }
        }
    }
}
```

End Update

Orginal question below:

I haven't got to the point where this routine is finished yet.

I was trying to follow a sample of code from this link. http://www.pocketmagic.net/2010/01/android-dynamic-tab-control/

However when I attempt to create a linearlayout for the tab being created the compiler freaks out on me. I'm not sure why it is throwing the error. It's like the object I made one line ago doesn't exist.

The **returned errors** are:

```
Multiple markers at this line
- Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
- Syntax error on token "params", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token
```

Anyways the **code** is below. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
//Create the tab host that contains the tab widget that contains the tabs
TabHost Tabs = new TabHost(this);
Tabs.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
//Create the tab widget  container
TabWidget TabWidget = new TabWidget(this);
TabWidget.setId(android.R.id.tabs);
Tabs.addView(TabWidget, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
Tabs.setup();
//Create the tabs
DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
String dbQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + dbHelper.System_Table + " AS s JOIN " +
    dbHelper.Devices_Table + " AS d ON s." + dbHelper.Attribute_Device_ID +
    " = d." + dbHelper.Attribute_Device_ID + ";";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(dbQuery, null);
if (c.getCount() > 0)
{
    while (c.moveToNext())
    {
        int iColumnDeviceType = c.getColumnIndex(dbHelper.Attribute_Device_Type);
        int iColumnDeviceName = c.getColumnIndex(dbHelper.Attribute_Device_Name);
        final String DeviceType = c.getString(iColumnDeviceType);
        String DeviceName = c.getString(iColumnDeviceName);
        String DeviceNameLabel = DeviceName.replaceAll(" ", "");
        TabSpec NewTab = Tabs.newTabSpec("tab" + DeviceNameLabel);
        NewTab.setIndicator(DeviceName);
        NewTab.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory()
        {
            LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
            LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            ll.setLayoutParams(params); //this line has both of the errors
            public View createTabContent(String tag)
            {
                    if (DeviceType == "Receiver")
                    {

                    }
                    else if (DeviceType == "Video Player")
                    {

                    }
                    return null; //place holder until I finish the routine
                }
            });
            Tabs.addTab(NewTab);
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you tried after moving layout creation lines inside createTabContent method ?

Comment: Have you used setContentView..??

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. I did just like you said ρяσѕρєя K and the error warning went away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue after much trial and error and googling an extensive ammount of examples.

First I gave up attempting to create the tab widget and the frame layout through java instead of xml for the activity..

In my activities layout xml file I added a tab control and in the xml view deleted the tabs leaving the xml code looking like this.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/MainLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >


            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in the java file for the activity I updated the oncreate routine to be this.

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//Create the tabs
TabHost Tabs = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
Tabs.setup();
DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
String dbQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + dbHelper.System_Table + " AS s JOIN " +
    dbHelper.Devices_Table + " AS d ON s." + dbHelper.Attribute_Device_ID +
    " = d." + dbHelper.Attribute_Device_ID + ";";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(dbQuery, null);
int Count = 0;
if (c.getCount() > 0)
{
    while (c.moveToNext())
    {
        Count = Count + 1;
        int iColumnDeviceType = c.getColumnIndex(dbHelper.Attribute_Device_Type);
        int iColumnDeviceName = c.getColumnIndex(dbHelper.Attribute_Device_Name);
        final String DeviceType = c.getString(iColumnDeviceType);
        final String DeviceName = c.getString(iColumnDeviceName);
        final String DeviceNameLabel = DeviceName.replaceAll(" ", "");
        Log.d("Creating Tab", "TabSpec: tab" + DeviceNameLabel);
        Log.d("Creating Tab", "Indicator: " + DeviceName);
        final TabSpec NewTab = Tabs.newTabSpec("tab" + DeviceNameLabel);
        NewTab.setIndicator(DeviceName);
        NewTab.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory()
        {
            @Override
            public View createTabContent(String tag)
            {
                LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
                LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                ll.setLayoutParams(params);
                ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                if (DeviceType.equals("Receiver"))
                {
                    final Button btnVolumeUp = new Button(MainActivity.this);
                    btnVolumeUp.setText("Volume Up");
                    btnVolumeUp.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    btnVolumeUp.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                    ll.addView(btnVolumeUp);
                }
                else if (DeviceType.equals("Video Player"))
                {
                    final Button btnPlay = new Button(MainActivity.this);
                    btnPlay.setText("Play");
                    btnPlay.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    btnPlay.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                    ll.addView(btnPlay);
                }
                return ll;
            }
        });

        Tabs.addTab(NewTab);

    }
}
```